# Parsing RSS Feed with SimpleXML

Tags: simplexml, feedparser, rss-reader

When I Run this code:

```
<?php
$rss = simplexml_load_file('http://stackoverflow.com/feeds');
?>
<h1><?php echo $rss->title; ?></h1>
<ul>
<?php
foreach($rss->entry as $e) {
    echo "<li><a href=\"".$e->link['href']."\">";
    echo $e->title;     
    echo "</a></li>\n";
}    
?>
</ul>
```

It generate following error:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://stackoverflow.com/feeds) [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/www/cheapflightshunt.co.uk/aaaa.php on line 2

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://stackoverflow.com/feeds" in /home/www/cheapflightshunt.co.uk/aaaa.php on line 2

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/www/cheapflightshunt.co.uk/aaaa.php on line 7
```

My shared hosting is running with  PHP5.2.17

Please provide the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may provide phpinfo() output for people to understand further. Possible causes can be 1) allow_url_fopen() is OFF 2) PHP4 doesn't support SimpleXML

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfectly. I suspect that your current settings doesn't [allow fopen over url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)

Try checking that.

If you can't change that setting, try CURL, instead:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('http://stackoverflow.com/feeds');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$rss = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
?>
<h1><?php echo $rss->title; ?></h1>
<ul>
<?php
foreach($rss->entry as $e) {
    echo "<li><a href=\"".$e->link['href']."\">";
    echo $e->title;     
    echo "</a></li>\n";
}    
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks @Repox But it still not working. I know there are no problems with the scripts but some settings are needed to be done on hosting. I have checked the **allow_url_fopen** & **allow_url_include** both are set to on. **CURL** is also enabled and your code is generating this error: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in /home/www/cheapflightshunt.co.uk/aaaa.php:6 Stack trace: #0 /home/www/cheapflightshunt.co.uk/aaaa.php(6): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('') #1 {main} thrown in /home/www/cheapflightshunt.co.uk/aaaa.php on line 6`

Comment: There must be something you're not telling us, because the code works fine - I think it's the URL of the RSS feed you're modifying for the question before posting it.